# What's the best way to extract a value from a scala case class?

Tags: scala, case-class

What would be the best and/or easiest way to extract a value that I've saved in a case class?

take for example the following code:

```
abstract class Something
case class Foo(input: Int) extends Something
case class Bar(input: Double) extends Something

def someMethod(a: Something, b: Something) {
    // code that extracts values goes here
}

someMethod(Foo(10), Foo(20))
someMethod(Bar(2.1), Bar(21.2))
```

how would I then go about getting the integer or the double itself out of `a` and `b` when I call the method like I did under its definition?

Note that both the parameters are used in the same equation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case classes constructor arguments are vals, so just call:

```
a.input
b.input
```

You can also use extractor with the help of `unapply` method:

```
val Foo(val1) = a
val Bar(val2) = b
```

and then use `val1` and `val2`

**Update**

Then you should use pattern matching on your value:

```
value match {
  case Foo(val1) => val1
  case Bar(val1) => val1
}
```

It works just like `val Foo(val1) = a`, with using generated `unapply` method (extractor) in your class, and it is also an expression, so you van assign the result to the variable

If you have multiple arguments just change PatMat construct according to the number of your parameters, in your case:

```
someMethod(a: Something, b: Something) = (a, b) match {
  case (Foo(v1), Foo(v2)) => (v1, v2) // or any other logic with values
  case (Foo(v1), Bar(v2)) => // logic for this case
  ... // logic for other cases
}
```

The more parameters the more cases you should provide, but you case blank cases if you don't need them

```
someMethod(a: Something, b: Something) = (a, b) match {
  case (Foo(v1), Foo(v2)) => (v1, v2) // or any other logic with values
  case _ => 
}
```

in this case all other cases will be ignored, not the best choice, cause the result type will be incorrect. And you also can black values

```
someMethod(a: Something, b: Something) = (a, b) match {
  case (Foo(v1), _) => v1 // in such case you can work only with v1
  ... // logic for other cases
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to pattern matching could be do redefine your classes like this:

```
trait Something[T]{
  def input:T
}
case class Foo(input: Int) extends Something[Int]
case class Bar(input: Double) extends Something[Double]
```

Then, any instance of `Something` will expose the `input` property.  The only potential downside is that it will be of a generic type when you access it.

Answer (score 3):

### The alternative approach

*In addition to the direct solution of* pattern matching *in your method, I'll try to show a somewhat more convoluted, general and functional approach to this kind of situations. Still pattern matching is the most* direct and simple *answer!*

---

If you can explicitly "certify" in your interface the `input` accessor, you can generalize how you work with the `Something` class.

In code this translates to

```
trait Something[T] {
  def input: T
}

case class Foo(input: Int) extends Something[Int]
case class Bar(input: Double) extends Something[Double]
```

---

from here you can define how to "lift" any function you like to one that works over `Something`s

Let's say you have methods that takes two inputs (e.g. `Ints` or `Doubles`) and you want to operate on such inputs within one of your case classes (i.e. `Foo`, `Bar`)

```
//this function lift your specific input method to one that takes Somethings
def liftSomething2[T, R](f: (T, T) => R): (Something[T], Something[T]) => R =
  (a, b) => f(a.input, b.input)
```

Let's examine this a bit: it takes a function
`(T, T) => R` of 2 arguments of type `T` and a result `R`

and transforms it in a
`(Something[T], Something[T]) => R` which takes `Something`s as arguments.

**Examples**

```
//lifts a function that sums ints
scala> val sumInts = liftSomething2[Int, Int](_ + _)
sumInts: (Something[Int], Something[Int]) => Int = <function2>

//lifts a function that multiplies ints
scala> val multInts = liftSomething2[Int, Int](_ * _)
multInts: (Something[Int], Something[Int]) => Int = <function2>

//lifts a function that divides doubles
scala> val divDbl = liftSomething2[Double, Double](_ / _)
divDbl: (Something[Double], Something[Double]) => Double = <function2>

//Now some test
scala> sumInts(Foo(1), Foo(2))
res2: Int = 3

scala> multInts(Foo(4), Foo(-3))
res3: Int = -12

scala> divDbl(Bar(20.0), Bar(3.0))
res4: Double = 6.666666666666667

//You can even complicate things a bit
scala> val stringApp = liftSomething2[Int, String](_.toString + _)
stringApp: (Something[Int], Something[Int]) => String = <function2>

scala> stringApp(Foo(1), Foo(2))
res5: String = 12
```

---

All the above examples lift functions of type `(T,T) => R` but the "lifting" can be made for all and any argument you need

```
//This takes three args of different types and returns another type
// the logic doesn't change
def liftSomething3[A,B,C,R](f: (A,B,C) => R): (Something[A], Something[B], Something[C]) => R =
  (a,b,c) => f(a.input, b.input, c.input)

//sums to ints and divides by a double
scala> val sumDiv = liftSomething3[Int,Int,Double,Double]((i,j,d) => (i + j) / d)
sumDiv: (Something[Int], Something[Int], Something[Double]) => Double = <function3>

scala> sumDiv(Foo(5), Foo(30), Bar(4.2))
res7: Double = 8.333333333333332
```

### more...

All we've seen so far should be somewhat related to *category theory* concepts like *Applicative Functors* and *Comonads*, but I'm no expert so I encourage you to search for yourself if you feel this sort of abstractions are useful and interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In your example both the `a` and `b` have specific types: `Foo` and `Bar` respectively. That's why you can simply access their fields like so:

```
scala> a.input
res4: Int = 10

scala> b.input
res5: Double = 25.1
```

If however your value has type `Something`, then you'll need to pattern-match:

```
val input = somethingOfTypeSomething match {
  case Foo(input) => input
  case Bar(input) => input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have covered the basic scenario. There are useful variations to consider.

**Constructor Pattern**

As already answered there is:

```
value match {
  case Foo(x) => x
  ...
}
```

**Deep Matching**

The constructor pattern also supports deep matching. For example, extract x within Bar within Foo which is 3 levels deep:

```
value match {
    case Foo(y, Bar(x)) => x
    ...
}
```

**Variable Binding**

If the value you want to extract is an actual case class inside another case class you can use variable binding. E.g. to extract the whole Bar(x) into b:

```
value match {
  case Foo(y, b @ Bar(x)) => b
  ...
}
```

**Programming in Scala** by M. Odersky, Spoon and Venners has a great chapter on case classes and pattern matching which covers many other scenarios. Pattern matching is such a rich part of the language it would be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: while books are good, they also tend to be expensive, and it'd take time for me to get to the part that would help me with my problem, which would mean I'd have to put the project on hiatus until I was done with it... This is exactly why I consult Stack Overflow, for quick useful answers... sorry